# an additional element within JAXB generated xml file

Tags: xml, jaxb

what's the role of this line in marshaling/unmarshaling using JAXB? when I delete it from the generated xml file the program return null. Is there any solution to avoid it? I want to read the xml files that generated using different technologies from different organizations:

```
<myRootEelement xmlns:ns2="myPackage.MyEntity" xmlns:ns3="myPackage.MyRootEntity">
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns` is an XML mechanism separate from JAXB.  The following line is assigning the namespace URI `myPackage.MyEntity` to the prefix `ns2` and the namespace URI `myPackage.MyRootEntity` to the prefix `ns3`.

```
<myRootEelement xmlns:ns2="myPackage.MyEntity" xmlns:ns3="myPackage.MyRootEntity">
```

Normally you would have elements in your XML document qualified with these prefixes.  In the example below the element `ns2:foo` has the local name `foo` and the namespace URI `myPackage.MyEntity`.

```
<myRootEelement xmlns:ns2="myPackage.MyEntity" xmlns:ns3="myPackage.MyRootEntity">
    <ns2:foo>Hello</ns2:foo>
    <ns3:bar>World</ns3:bar>
</myRootEelement>
```

The URIs in your example are odd.  A URI should include a schema and look like `http://wwww.example.com/foo`.  I am guessing that the XML document is misusing them.  For an example see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: thanks, but I don't use any @XmlType(namespace= or @XmlSchema(namespace= within my code so I don't know how the java-to-xml method generate them and why when I delete them from the generated file the xml-to-java method return null for myPackage.MyEntity?

Comment: @nazila - Can you post some code that demonstrates this issue?  Are you sure that you are using JAXB?

Comment: The tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html and the code: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/fdlmadum7nb9xao/JAXBTutorialExample.zip and also how can I have multiple country tags within a file? I created an additional object (myPackage.MyRootEntity) which contains a list of myPackage.MyEntity as Country here.